# Is it bad practice to display user input in JSON responses for error messages?

Tags: json, rest, security

I've been of the opinion that error messages should display as little information as possible to prevent any hints an attacker could use to gain access to sensitive information.

Here's an example. This endpoint accepts the optional request parameter `group` which could be the ID or name of the group.

`POST /sign-in/?group=[group_id_or_name]`.

Also accepted is HTTP basic auth for username and password.

Before the username and password validation check, the code checks if the group is valid and exists or not.

If the group is invalid, REST API returns a bad request with the error message:

> The requested group is invalid.

But an alternative is to display this error message:

> The requested group [prints requested_group_parameter value here] is
>   invalid.

Yes, the requested group is already available in the request parameter, but is there any possibility the user could inject bad input into the request and have it show malicious information?

Are there any questionable practices here or is this all trivial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be careful when returning, as there might have been an SQL injection attack (or buffer overflow, or XSS, or some other attack that I may be forgetting - depending on your scenario). These should be taken care of anyway, but if you return the result of a query, it might be easier for an attacker to perform such attacks (again, depending on your code and scenario).

Besides that, since the group is originating from the client, therefore a user can see it by inspecting the code of the page, or by using some browser add-on, I don't see any problems. Assuming that there are no attacks like the ones described above, the user will only be able to see what he/she typed as a group name. So sending either of the two messages is fine.

Now, if the names of the groups are sensitive information and you don't want them to leak, in order to prevent a brute force attack, you should not send *any* message back at the point of checking the group name. You should instead continue the whole procedure as if the group name was correct, ask for username and password, check if these are correct (in order to avoid timing attacks) and only then return that the group, username, or password are wrong or don't exist. However, if by having credentials you can login to any group, this method still fails, as someone who has credentials and gets an error message can easily understand that the incorrect information is the group name.